# office 365 login Authentication in my application

Tags: office365

We are planning to give provision for user to login with Office 365 account..
I would like to know any forum to guide to integrate this.

My Application API : WebAPi (C#)
Front end: Angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following example:

```
   protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{  
    bool result = false;  

    HttpResponse < string > response = Unirest.get("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/").basicAuth(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text).asJson < string > ();  

    if (response.Code == 200)  
        result = true;  

    if (result)   
    {  
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('User validated successfully')", true);  
    } else  
    {  
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Email/Password is wrong')", true);  
    }  
}
```

You will get the data as below. This is sample data.

```
{  
"@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me",  
"@odata.id": "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('yourName@companyName.com')",  
"Id": "yourId",  
"DisplayName": "Your Display Name",  
"Alias": "aliasName",  
"MailboxGuid": "mailBoxGuid"  
}
```

For more information, please see the following links:

[Authentication With Office 365 In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-with-office-365-in-C-Sharp/)

[Office 365 Authentication using Visual Studio MVC application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1033978/Office-Authentication-using-Visual-Studio-MVC-appl)

Comment: I need the same implementation for v2 with username and password with my own web app login